# To how many decimal places is floating point guaranteed to be same for every machine?

Tags: floating-point

I need to make sure that a demo of a player playing my game-- *which is saved as keystrokes--* is 100% reproducible on all machines. Floating points are not guaranteed to be 100% safe (I can't just use integers because the game's world is not totally orthogonal and such) and so inaccuracies will inevitably add up on different machines, causing the playback to be broken-- or rather: they can add up and cause it to break.

I'm fairly certain that a floating point number will be the same from system to system for a *few* decimal places, so I've decided to use floating points but round every one to... **how many decimal places?** ...before saving them for later use in the program.

For extra certainty, I suppose that I could always make a program that checks every possible float-producing calculation against a list of "standard results" 
to see if a machine is fit for the task.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Zero.

If there is **any** deviation between results on two machines, it can potentially grow arbitrarily large in further calculations, depending on the mathematics and algorithms involved.

Generally, deviations in simple arithmetic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and even square root) will start at  or below the level of one ULP. (An ULP is the Unit of Least Precision, the lowest bit represented in the value.) These deviations can occur because different compilers may use different precisions for evaluating floating-point expressions. For example, even though you use `float` operands, the compiler may use `double` precision while calculating. A system that uses `float` precision will get different answers from one that uses `double` precision.

In more complicated operations, such as calls to the math library routines such as `pow`, `sin`, and `log`, there may be larger differences. Essentially no commercial math libraries implement these routines with *correctly rounded* results. (A result is *correctly rounded* if it is produced as if the exact mathematical result were rounded to the nearest representable result using a specified rounding rule, such as always upward [toward ∞] or always toward the nearest with ties to the even low bit.) It is not uncommon for math library routines to return results that are off by a few ULP (sometimes many more in poor-quality implementations), and the libraries of different vendors will return different results.

In order to reproduce identical results on different platforms, you need to closely control the floating-point operations. Few compilers provide good support for this. Hardware support for IEEE 754 arithmetic is widespread, so you can get reproducible results by using assembly language and avoiding various pitfalls. (One pitfall is spreading calculations over multiple threads or other non-deterministic execution. Another is processors that flush subnormal values to zero by default instead of returning the proper IEEE 754 result.)

You write “I've decided to use floating points but round every one…” This is not an uncommon notion, but it is flawed. One problem with this is that it magnifies errors near rounding points. For example, suppose you were rounding to the nearest multiple of 1 (quite large, but this is just for illustration). So 2.49 would be rounded to 2, and 2.51 would be rounded to 3. What happens if on one platform the result is 2.499 and on another it is 2.501? Then the results are rounded to 2 and 3. Now you have changed a small difference between two platforms and made it a large difference.

Comment: Your answer is much appreciated. So, how *should* I go about making 100% reproducible (on a "theoretical and computational" level, ie ignoring the potential effects of quantum mechanics and such) demo recorder for my game that I'm writing in LÖVE? And for the rounding problem, what if I just floor them? This might be a really stupid thing to say, but I'm tired and dehydrated (as usual) so please be patient.

Comment: @wolfboyft: Getting identical floating-point results on multiple platforms is not easy and cannot be answered in a comment. You can search Stack Overflow for “[floating-point] reproducibility” for some information. Bottom line, you need to use assembly language or at least extensions beyond standard programming languages to control the machine state, you must restrict compilers to strictly IEEE-754 conforming operations without extra precision or contractions, and you cannot rely on any vendor math libraries or other platform-specific math libraries. It is not an easy task.

Comment: @wolfboyft: Floor will not work. That is just another rounding method. The problem with any rounding method is that it there are points *x* where a value slightly below *x* rounds down and a value slightly above *x* rounds up, and therefore any calculation errors near *x* are magnified. Floating-point is intended to approximate continuous (real) arithmetic, so applying any non-continuous function like rounding/truncation conflicts with that.